# Find the slope of a line passing through P(2,3) and intersecting the line $x+y=7$ and at a distance of 4 units from P.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Let the point of intersection be (h,k)

Using the symmetric form
$$\frac{h-2}{\cos \theta}=4$$
$$h=4\cos \theta+2$$ and $$k=4\sin \theta+3$$
Since (h,k) lies on $x+y=7$
$$2\cos \theta+2\sin \theta-1=0$$
I found the value of $\sin \theta$ by squaring on both sides and solving the quadratic to be 
$$\sin \theta=\frac{1\pm\sqrt 7}{4}$$
From here I can find $\cos \theta$ and subsequently $\tan \theta=m$

What what about the $\pm$? Only one of the answer is valid, how do I find out which is the right one?

Comment: why do you say only one answer is valid?

Comment: I edited tags because this question has nothing to do with conic sections.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner it was an MCQ, and there were two options which had the same numbers but different signs

Comment: If It was a single correct answer then, the question is wrong else it has multiple correct answers. Since the information provided by you only helps to locate the two intersection points on the given straight line. If any additional information is provided then we can uniquely determine the slope and equation.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

As the point of intersection$Q$ must lie on $x+y=7$

$Q(h,7-h)$

Now $4^2=(2-h)^2+(7-h-3)^2$

Clearly the above quadratic equation has two distinct real roots, 
each one corresponds to one possible position of $Q$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the two tangents $m=\tan\theta$ corresponding to $\sin \theta=\frac{1\pm\sqrt 7}{4}$ are respectively,

$$m_1= -\frac{4+\sqrt7}3=-2.22,\>\>\>\>\>\>\>m_2 = -\frac{4-\sqrt7}3=-0.45$$

The options in your MCQ should contain one of the two solutions above. So, check $m_1$ and $m_2$ against the choices and identify the matching one.